# Disconnect user with python (discord bot)

Tags: python, command, client, discord.py, disconnect

I tried to make a command that disconnect user but could not understand why does it give me this error: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'
(this is just part of the bot code)

```
@client.command
async def leave(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    await discord.Member.disconnect()



 if msg.startswith("$kick."):
        users = message.guild.members
        count = 6
        name = ""
        while count < len(message.content):
            name = name + str(message.content[count])
            count = count + 1
        #till here we just got the name
        x = 0
        while x > id.member_count:
            if name == users[x]:
                leave('was kicked',user[x])
                break
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `()` after `@client.command`. Change it to `@client.command()`